# Videojs v451 if width 100% in video tag the script writes this: height 150px

Tags: css, width

I just added `width=100%` for VIDEO, and the Script writes `height=150px`:

`div id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-controls-enabled vjs-has-started vjs-paused vjs-user-inactive" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;` ....

Why this 150px ?

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="video.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="100%" 
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup="{}">
  <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
  <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>

 </body>
 </html>
```